# Automatically move sent mail to inbox in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

In Lotus Notes when you send an email it can automatically put the email in your "Sent" view.  But the "Sent" view is special in that you can't move messages "out" of the sent view to some other folder.  You can "copy" messages into another folder and then delete messages from the "Sent" view.  But this is a very tedious two step process.  So typically what I do every day is I copy all my "Sent" mail into the Inbox and then delete all mail from the "Sent" view.

During my commute every day I process all the days messages filing them away in the appropriate folder for later reference.  So having everything in the Inbox saves TONS of time since most messages on a similar topic (sent/received) show up beside each other in the timeline.

Is there an automated way to get Lotus Notes to move messages automatically from the "Sent" folder to the "Inbox" on a regular basis.  I have heard that I can do with with a Scheduled Agent but I don't see any way to schedule an agent (Note: I am a user not a Domino Admin).

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK first thing to realise is that Folders and Views are two different things.

- A view will list documents based on a pre-defined search criteria.
- A folder contains documents that have been marked as being in that folder.

So you can't "move" a document from a view to a folder as they have no real connection to each other.

What you can do is remove a document from the view by having it fail the search criteria. In this case here is the code for the sent view.

```
SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView))
```

This means the following.

> Show the document in the view if the field "DeliveredDate" is blank
>   and PostedDate is not blank, and the field ExcludeFromView does not
>   contain an "S".

So the quickest way to remove it is to add an "S" to the existing value in the ExcludeFromView field.

Now to add it to the inBox folder you can just move the document to that folder.

**DISCLAIMER:** I have not tested this agent, use at your own risk.

You should be able to do both by creating a simple agent with the following (use Add Condition button to create them).

[image: Simple Agent]

Then clicking on "Document Selection" you can specify to check documents only in the sent view.

[image: Document Selection]

Lastly right click on the white area and select Agent properties. You can specify how you want it to run (scheduled or from menu).

*Example:*

[image: run settings]

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for the help.  Can't believe that I didn't see the "schedule trigger" in the properties view (brain cramp).  I have installed the agent and it's working perfectly.  The "Sent" view is kind of schizophrenic in Notes in that it maintains "state" so it's not a simple "view" query in that things can manually be "suppressed" from the view so the 'ExcludeFromView does not contain an "S"' part was the stumper.  Kudos for the quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is simply to be able to see your sent messages and received messages in one place, you don't have to do anything at all!  The answer isn't to move messages around.  The answer is to open the All Documents view.

[image: Picture of All Documents view]

The sent messages have a little envelope icon next to them.

This is from a Notes 8.5 client, but all versions of Notes do have this view.

There's also a Mail Threads view, which organizes messages and responses into hierarchical threads (when possible; sometimes it's not).  I don't recall what version of Notes this was introduced in, but it's definitely there in Notes 8 and may be what you really need most.

Comment: I'd have to go with this one. :) Sometimes what you want and what you need are two different things.

Comment: I know what you are talking about.  The issue here is that I am trying to "sort" email into the respective folders at the end of a day so I need to know if I have processed the email or not so the All Documents view wouldn't help me there.  (Note: I am doing this on the train via my BlackBerry not in Notes so it's much easier to have everything in my Inbox and sort stuff from there)

Comment: If that's the case, then Simon's method does seem like the way to go.  BTW: In the Notes client, there's a Send-and-File feature that lets you select the folder for your Sent messages as you go. On the other hand, if you do a lot of sending from your BlackBerry I'm not sure that feature's available there,  Plus, what would you do in the evening commute time if all your messages were already filed? ;-)